# @PropertySource and @Autowired environment - null

Tags: properties

Environment variable 'env' is null. Why?

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "src.main.resources" })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PropertiesUtil {

@Autowired
private static Environment env;
```

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me solve my problem :

http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/spring-env-properties/